# How to fix **error: cannot find symbol** when importing kotlin package into MainApplication.java for Android in React Native app?

Tags: java, android, react-native, kotlin

I'm building a react native app that uses the react-native-vision-camera by  Mrousavy (https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) and I'm trying to create a frame processor plugin, following this guide https://mrousavy.com/react-native-vision-camera/docs/guides/frame-processors-plugins-android, which is basically a piece of native code, in this case Kotlin, that process the camera stream, frame by frame.

However, I've tried it several times and I keep getting this error related to Kotlin/Java code:

```
error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: ./gradlew app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081
Warning: unexpected element (uri:"", local:"base-extension"). Expected elements are <{}codename>,<{}layoutlib>,<{}api-level>
/home/luciano/wildsense/nam-vital-signs/rn/RNCamera0/android/app/src/main/java/com/rncamera0/MainApplication.java:16: error: cannot find symbol
import com.rncamera0.BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage;
                    ^
  symbol:   class BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage
  location: package com.rncamera0
/home/luciano/wildsense/nam-vital-signs/rn/RNCamera0/android/app/src/main/java/com/rncamera0/MainApplication.java:33: error: cannot find symbol
          packages.add(new BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage());
                           ^
  symbol: class BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage
Note: /home/luciano/wildsense/nam-vital-signs/rn/RNCamera0/android/app/src/debug/java/com/rncamera0/ReactNativeFlipper.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
```

As far as I understand, there's a problem with how I'm importing and using the class `BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage` but nothing of what I've tried fix it.

The file that contains the error (MainApplication.java), and the two files for the code I want to add (BasicFrameProcessorPlugin.kt and BasicFrameProcessorPluginPackage.kt) are in the same directory(`.../android/app/src/main/java/com/rncamera0`), and all of them have `package com.rncamera0` as the first line.

Being that said, I will appreciate any help to find the solution to the error.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this? I've got this problem as well.

Comment: @TomKulaga I didn't solve it directly, mainly because I didn't have more time to invest on this. So what I'm doing right now is manage the frame processor as a npm package, which you can create with react-native-builder-bob or create-react-native-module, anyway none of those worked for me so I made a fork of vision-camera-ocr and worked from that. Also here are the links of related questions in [https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/issues/1124 ](github) and [https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/vyf8nq/comment/iggjfi1/?context=3 ](reddit), the last one should help you

Comment: apply plugin: 'kotlin-android' // add kotlin-android plugin
 adding that fixed it. I had removed it after some confusion with reanimated.

Comment: @TomKulaga You should post that as an answer. If you get error **error: cannot find symbol** when importing kotlin package into MainApplication.java you need to make sure that Kotlin included in your project gradle.